# Rails & Mailgun: emails not sending

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailgun

I have an app that sends out email notifications. Some users have mentioned they are not receiving notifications.

NotificationMailer.rb:

```
  def send_daily_digest(user_id)
      @user = User.find(user_id)
      mail(to: @user.email, subject: "#{@jobs.count} new jobs yesterday")
      mail(to: "myadminemail@gmail.com", subject: "TEST #{@jobs.count} new jobs yesterday for #{@user.email}")
  end
```

My email is myadminemail@gmail.com and I am receiving the email. I checked Mailgun logs and the other (non admin) email is not being sent.

What could be causing this?

EDIT: I just made the below change:

```
def send_daily_digest(user_id)
          @user = User.find(user_id)
          @recipients = []
          @recipients << @user.email
          @recipients << myadminemail@gmail.com
          mail(to: @recipients, subject: "#{@jobs.count} new jobs yesterday")
      end
```

Making that change properly sent out the email to both recipients. So maybe it has something to do with not being allowed to have two separate mail_to actions?

My issue now is that both recipients are CC'd on the email. I want the emails to be separate and direct to each user. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you checked if the other email address has not been blocked?
If you happen to send emails to a test address, the rejected address may be blocked by Railgun.

Comment: Hi @Lomefin see my edits. The other address has not been blocked. I've just confirmed this.

Answer (score 0):

/config/environments/development.rb

```
 config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :authentication => :plain,
      :address => "smtp.mailgun.org",
      :port => 587,
      :domain => "you domain  in https://mailgun.com/app/",
      :user_name => "you user_name in https://mailgun.com/app/",
      :password => "you password in https://mailgun.com/app/"
  }
```

Comment: Hmmm.. yes I have the proper setup because my emails are sending fine to my first address

Comment: Maybe instead of setting the raise_delivery_errors to false, you could set them up to true so we can verify if there is any problem within rails sending the first email.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Rails Docs about ActionMailer](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#method-i-mail) the mail method is the main method that creates the message and renders the email templates.

That means is equivalent to ActionController#render so maybe it just sends the mail to the last recipient invoked by the mail method.

So maybe what you should do is to move the delivery logic to a object controlling the mailer.

For example I call these objects dispatchers.

```
class ClientDispatcher
  def self.dispatch_digests
    Clients.all.each do |client|
      DigestMailer.send_daily_digest(client).deliver_later
      DigestMailer.send_daily_digest("admin@gmail.com").deliver_later
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I came back here to compliment.
The mail method does add some information to the message but this is not sent immediately, that is why the information is appended and not sent separately.

You can read the [mail method source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/base.rb#L854)